# openstack cinder cant create,and cinder list ,openstack volume service list show "The server is currently unavailable."

Tags: openstack-cinder

i have installed cinder in controller node and block node.
i test the status of openstack-cinder-scheduler and openstack-cinder-api(on controller node) ,openstack-cinder-volume and target.service(on block node),that they are running.
but when i use the "cinder list,cinder create,openstack volume service list"only can get one kind of output:

[root@controller //]# openstack volume service list
The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.

(HTTP 503)
[root@controller //]# cinder list
ERROR: The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.
The Keystone service is temporarily unavailable.

i have check the configure in cinder.conf,nova.conf serveral times.i have no idea with them.can u give a suggestion? thank you.

Comment: the openstack version is train,i install it by following the guides from docs.openstack.org

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can create volume by dashboard, while by command line I can't. It may be something wrong between admin and cinder user.  Try it again.

```
[root@controller //]# openstack volume list  
+--------------------------------------+----------+-----------+------+-------------+  
| ID                                   | Name     | Status    | Size | Attached to |  
+--------------------------------------+----------+-----------+------+-------------+  
| 435acaae-44d8-4793-9a0c-61a4436b6b37 | volumev4 | available |    1 |             |  
+--------------------------------------+----------+-----------+------+-------------+  

[root@controller //]# openstack role add --project service --user cinder admin    
 [root@controller //]# openstack volume service list  
+------------------+--------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+  
| Binary           | Host         | Zone | Status  | State | Updated At                   |    
+------------------+--------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+  
| cinder-scheduler | controller   | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-12-28T07:40:01.000000 |  
| cinder-volume    | compute2@lvm | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-12-28T07:40:07.000000 |  
+------------------+--------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+
```

it has the output.